# Why does getWidth() is larger than getLayoutParams().width sometimes?

Tags: android, android-layout

My code for fixing `ImageView`:

```
private void fixImageWidth() {
    int parentHeight = getHeight();
    if (parentHeight == 0 || getParent() == null)
        return;

    Drawable drawable = image.getDrawable();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
    if (drawable != null) {
        int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        lp.width = (int) ((float)(parentHeight - lp.topMargin * 2) / height * width);
    } else {
        lp.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    }

    image.requestLayout();
}
```

But sometimes actually image bounds is not changed. Below you could see HierarchyViewer properties of that object:

[image: HierarchyView properties]

**EDIT:**

After I lot for debugging I determined, sometimes requestLayout don't remeasure image view. How does this happens?

**EDIT:**

I found solution, but still don't know reason. Solution is below:

```
    image.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            image.requestLayout();
        }
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible that `layout_width` is specified in `dp`, and `getWidth()` returns pixels. That would explain the 1.5x difference, especially if you're using an hdpi device.

Comment: @Geobits I am sure layout_width is specified in dp, because other views with same drawable and same height has layout_width=75 and getWidth() == 75.

Comment: That explains it then, because I'm sure that `getWidth()` is in px: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth()

Comment: Layout_width is also in pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Because getWidth() and getLayoutParams().width are different things. 1st relates to the View, the second is a layout request to the parent. If the parent cannot match the request the View maybe laid out with a different width. In this case you have requested MATCH_PARENT in the layout height and since an ImageView has a default scaleType of FIT_CENTER therefore content aspect ratio is maintained so the width will change.

Comment: I set `adjustViewBounds` to false. Why `requestLayout` doesn't remeasure and recalculate width by new `getLayoutParams().width` settings?

Comment: I determined issue. `View.requestLayout` doesn't remeasure image sometimes. Why could this happen?